# Cat in expect script adds new line to end of string

Tags: linux, cat, output, newlines, expect

I have the following in an `expect` script

```
spawn cat version
expect -re 5.*.*
set VERSION $expect_out(0,string)
spawn rpm --addsign dist/foo-$VERSION-1.i686.rpm
```

The `cat` command is getting the version correctly however it appears to be adding a new line. Since I expect the output to be the following:

`dist/foo-5.x.x-1.i686.rpm`

but am getting including the error at the begining the following:

```
cannot access file dist/foo-5.x.x
-1.i686.rpm
```

Why is `expect` adding a new line to the `cat` command output and is there any way to have this not be done or to fix the output of the cat command?

Comment: What are the contents of the file and what do you need? TCL can read files without spawning `cat`...

Comment: it's not `cat` that's adding a newline, it's the `rpm` command that's outputting the error

Comment: @thrig the contents of the file just say 5.x.x no other text in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCL can read a file directly without the complication of `spawn cat`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# open a (read) filehandle to the "version" file... (will blow up if the file
# is not found)
set fh [open version]
# and this call handily discards the newline for us, and since we only need
# a single line, the first line, we're done.
set VERSION [gets $fh]

# sanity check value read before blindly using it...
if {![regexp {^5\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$} $VERSION]} {
    error "version does not match 5.x.y"
}

puts "spawn rpm --addsign dist/foo-$VERSION-1.i686.rpm"
```

Answer (score 5):

You most likely have a newline character at the end of your `version` file, so `expect` isn't so much adding a newline as it is blindly doing what you told it to. IMHO, it would be easier to adjust the expect script to strip out any newlines before spawning the `rpm` command, and it would ensure you don't run into this issue again if a different edit put the terminating newline back even after you've removed it.

Even if you don't have a terminating newline in the `version` file, I woud still advise you to add a `strip()` call (adjusting to the correct syntax for `expect`, of course) to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As thrig says, you should read the file directly. Also, using `cat`, as John says there will be a newline at the end of the file, and this will become `\r\n` (carriage-return, newline) on passing through the pty of `spawn`.  So you can change your regex pattern to only capture upto these characters:

```
expect -re "(5.*)\r\n"
set VERSION $expect_out(1,string)
```

Note how we ask for index 1, the capture `()`, not 0, the whole pattern match.

Alternatively, you can remove the whitespace with the `tcl` command

```
set VERSION [string trim $expect_out(0,string)]
```

Note, you are confusing glob and regexp patterns in your expect line: `5.*.*` as a glob pattern will match your *5.x.x* style of input. Using `-re` means you should just use regexp `5.*` which matches all to the end.